# block pushing to origin/master unless through jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm new to continuous integration and I'm just now starting to check out Jenkins, as I'm doing this I'm trying to work out what exactly it is I really need to happen. I would like to prevent pushing to the master branch unless through a Jenkins job that will build/test/validate etc so that the master branch is a clean working copy that is ready for use on any dev machine at any time. I would use a feature branch workflow alongside this.

How exactly can I implement this? Is there a better solution that I have yet to read about?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This will help https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/dont-phunk-my-stable-branch-jenkins-pre-tested-commits-stop-breaking-stable-branches

You wouldn't usually have developers pushing to master, rather to a "develop" or "integration" branch as illustrated here. The link is pretty detailed in terms of setup.

### Configuring Jenkins:

1. Project -> Configure -> Source Code Management -> Git. Setup to get the integration branch.
2. Select Merge before Build. With details for your master branch.
3. Post Build -> Git Publisher. Check "Push only if build succeeds, and enter details for your master branch.

Now jenkins is configured to merge the integration branch into master if the build succeeds. This assumes that your repository is setup and has a branch called integration. Another thing you can do is to setup build triggers to trigger the build automatically.

Comment: You should add some more details to your answer other than the link. The link is not guaranteed to survive... But apart from that it looks pretty good.

Comment: It's wide open if you feel like transcribing the Cloudbees blog post

Answer (score 0):

Have your repo work with two refs for each branch, the base branch and the validation branch.  Your pre-receive exit rejects pushes to the base branch, and your post-receive queues up a jenkins job for the new SHA on pushes to the validation branch.

That jenkins job fast-forwards the base branch on each success, so for instance master and master-validation are playing the marching-ants trick.  On failure, the jenkins job forces the validation branch back to the base ref and flushes any pending jobs for that branch.

It looks like [Fo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35447616/1290731) links to a description of a more complicated system involving automatic merging and multiple repos.